# Partition not showing when installing Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, partition, system-installation, partition-table

My current OS is Windows 10.I am installing Ubuntu 17.04 from pendrive. When I run Ubuntu in TRY MODE (without installing) then it shows all partitions- sda2,3,4,5; see the screenshot:

[image: Showing all the partitions sda2,3,4,5]

But when I the run the installer then the partition sda 5 is not visible,and also the size of all partitions change:

[image: Not showing the partitions when I run the installer]

I don't want to lose the data from sda3,4,5. I am ready to delete data from /dev/sda2 because it has only windows on it.
Why correct partioning is not showing? Do I need to use any tool for that? All type of solutions are welcome. Thanks in Advance :-)

The output of lsblk command is as follows:

[image]

The picture of command execution and also showing screen which I get at Install now:

[image]

Comment: These look like two completely different hard disks. Please open a terminal, run `cat /proc/partitions` and `lsblk` and append the output to your question.

Comment: No they are not different hard disk. the difference between 2 screenshots is only that the second pic was clicked when I clicked on 'Install Now'

Comment: At this time I am running Windows 10 on it. How can I append that?
 Should I shutdown and take a picture of it?    @MartinvonWittich

Comment: As Martin suggested, run `lsblk` while in *try mode* and add the output to the question.

Comment: I have added the output of lsblk Please give it a view @MartinvonWittich

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what could be going on here. The only idea I can come up with is that there may be some kind of bug in the Ubuntu installer so that it reports incorrect data for your hard disk. Maybe there are conflicting partition tables on your disk (MBR and GPT), and Linux reads one while the Ubuntu installer reads the other?

Comment: I don't think that there  is any bug in installer because I have tried other  Distros also.

Comment: But you are nearly right on part of having 2 conflicting partition tables, I had this clue from some output of some commands too. So what can I do now to make other table appear in installer?

Comment: I'd advise you to make a full backup of all the data on that hard disk, and then properly repartition and reformat it. If you really have conflicting partition tables, you are in serious risk of data loss; attempting to fix that might easily destroy all the data you have on that disk.

Comment: Yaa thanks @MartinvonWittich I did the same way and got everything safely

Comment: Revisiting this question after a long time and I know how much efforts I had putten to do that, but sometimes there is no good way to do a thing. I had to do the bad thing- to copy the data manually to external harddisk.

In case someone faces this then they should try everything mentioned above, at end they should think about copying to external hard disk.